# Using I've Known With Past Year

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions

Someone wished me a great year on my birthday, and I wanted to reply like that:
Hope it'll be a great year like the past one where I've known such a beautiful inside-outside soul, thanks, dear.
Is this sentence right? I used present perfect because he still my friend and the past year is the time we met together, and also is it right to use where instead of when for the year?

Answer (score 2):

The use of present perfect is good.  And the use of "where" to mean "in which" is common and idiomatic.

I don't understand the rest of the sentence:  I don't know what a "beautiful inside-outside soul" is.  I don't know why you say "dear"  (we might use "dear" to refer to a husband or wife but not to "someone").  I'd be very surprised to get a reply like this if I wished someone a great year.

It is very common to express good wishes on someone's birthday, and there isn't an expectation of a reply. So if I were you I would remove everything except "thanks".

Comment: "dear" isn't exclusive to married couples

Comment: Perhaps not, but it is unusual to refer to someone outside your family as "dear"

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much, I have a crush on him hhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @Bayan Harb Oh, seriously? AHAHHAHAHAHAHHAHA